# How can I get my Tryparse working?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

I need to use `TryParse` but I don't really know and where I suppose to put it. I want the user to be able to enter any value and prevent the program to crash.

```
string[] userInput = new string[5];            
bool isRunning = true;
while (isRunning) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("[1]Lägg till ett föremål");
    Console.WriteLine("[2]Skriv ut innehållet");
    Console.WriteLine("[3]Sök i ryggsäcken");

    int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (menyVal)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Write("Lägg till ett föremål: ");
            userInput[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Lägg till andra föremål: ");
            userInput[1] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Lägg till tredje föremål: ");
            userInput[2] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Lägg till fjärde föremål: ");
            userInput[3] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Lägg till femte föremål: ");
            userInput[4] = Console.ReadLine();
             break;

        case 2:

            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
            {   
                Console.WriteLine(userInput[i]);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
                   Console.Write("Skriv in sökOrd: ");
            string sökOrd = Console.ReadLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
            {
                if (userInput[i].ToUpper() == sökOrd.ToUpper())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userInput[i]);
                    break; 
                }
            } 
            break;

        case 4:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: ``int menyVal; int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menyVal);``

Comment: Could you please translate your sample to english so that question is understandable to broader audience? And I believe you are able to shorten the sample as well, right?

Comment: Try out your program by inputting an `A` (or any non-number) where your program asks for a number. See where it breaks. Then try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do by using TryParse by using Following lines of code

```
string Input= Console.ReadLine();
int menyVal = 0;
int.TryParse(Input, out menyVal);
```

Comment: With C# 7 (Visual studio 2017), you can also just do `int.TryParse(Input, out int menyVal);`.  No need to declare the variable on the previous line.

Comment: You should also check the return value from `TryParse` so that you know for sure if the value was successfully parsed or not.

Comment: string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int value = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You enter the number {0}", value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value you enter is not a number");
            }

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm just a beginner.